# Get only second word from bash history

Tags: bash, grep, history

I am trying to get only second word from output of `history` command using *only* grep. So far I have the regex:

`[^\d\s](\w+)`

Same input:

`10004  history --help
10005  history -h
10006  man history
10007  history
10008  sort history | uniq -c
10009  history | sort | uniq -c
10010  history | sort
10011  PATH
10012  compgen -c
10013  compgroups
10014  compgroups -a
10015  whence -pm '*'
10016  history | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+'`

which selects everything after the numbers but also everything after the second word (the command in this case).

How do I fine tune this to what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\d+\s+([^\s]+)\s+
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Thanks! yours selects numbers as well which I negated and I have: `[^\d+\s+]([^\s]+)` but the same regex seems to select more than the second word in regexpal.com. what am i missing here?

Comment: Every regex engine is different, though this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: and your regex demo only shows selection of second word in first line. no matching is happening for rest of the input. that isnt what i was expecting

Comment: Your regex captures required match in `submatch 1` or `$1` in perl context. `grep` would print `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ history | grep -oP '^\s*\d+\s*\K[^ ]+'
```

This uses `-P` option to use `pcre` as positive lookbehind is needed

- `^\s*\d+\s*\K` means any space at start of line followed by digits and any spaces - not part of output
- `[^ ]+` extract string of characters other than space, thus getting second `word` as you put it in question

Comment: I was just typing an answer with `\K`... You beat me :D... +1